# How to make an actor in Gridworld change its image?

Tags: java, gridworld

I know that if I have say a Boulder class extend Bug then if there is a Boulder.gif file  in the project folder it will use that as its image. I can also change the image's color whenever I want to with the setColor() method. However, within the program, how can I change the thing's image? Eg. if it hits the edge it turns and changes its image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can. You can make it change into another `Actor` that has a different image but does the same thing as the `Boulder`.

This is what I use to do this type of thing:

```
public void changeBoulder()
{
    int boulderDirection = getDirection(); 
    Actor newActor = new NewActor();
    Grid<Actor> gr = getGrid();
    Location loc = getLocation(); 

    newActor.putSelfInGrid(gr, loc);
    newActor.setDirection(boulderDirection);
}
```

Using this code your new `Actor` will be in the same `Location` and facing the same `Direction`.